# attempt to index A nil Value in LUA for CS50 in a PONG game

Tags: lua

I've trying to run this program, well, the main works just fine but when I try to run the reset function It says that  Ball.lua:14: attempt to index global 'self'(a nil value)

I'm really new to LUA so I'm not sure how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

```
Ball = Class{}

function Ball:init(x, y, width, height)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.dx = math.random(2) == 1 and -100 or 100
    self.dy = math.random(-50, 50)
end

function Ball.reset()
    --start ball's position in middle
    self.x = VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 2
    self.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 2

    self.dx = math.random(2) == 1 and -100 or 100
    self.dy = math.random(-50, 50) * 1.5
end

function Ball:update(dt)
    self.x = self.x + self.dx * dt
    self.y = self.y + self.dy * dt
end

function Ball:render()
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end
```

Comment: Typo: change `Ball.reset` to `Ball:reset`

Comment: Thank you very much.
I can't belive It sliped my view. It solved everything